# Atributo "life" do componente Growl funciona apenas na primeira vez

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estamos realizando um projeto em JSF usando PrimeFaces (v5.0) e criamos uma validação simples para campos em branco no nosso formulário.

Da primeira vez que é disparado, o componente realiza as ações de forma correta. Caso o usuário esqueça novamente algum campo em branco, a segunda vez que o p:growl é chamado ele simplesmente fica permanentemente na tela, mesmo o atributo sticky setado para false.

Abaixo o growl que utilizo junto com um exemplo de campo que verifico para validação:

```
<p:growl id="growl" sticky="false" life="1800"/>

<h:outputLabel for="nomePessoa" value="Nome Completo"/>
<p:inputText type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="nomePessoa"value="#{PessoaMB.pessoa.nome}" placeholder="Nome" required="true" requiredMessage="Nome não informado!">
```

Comment: Coloca mais código por favor, a ponto que possamos simular.

Comment: Douglas, já consegui solucionar o problema usando javascript. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso:

```
<p:growl id="growl" sticky="false" autoUpdate="true" life="1800"/>
```